# Eclipse PDE -  marker annotation type - the background color is not updated

Tags: eclipse

I'm a student and as a part of the yearly project I'm developing eclipse plug-in.
I've encountered a weird problem and trying to fix it for 2 days now:

I've added 3 new types of markers in the `plugin.xml`.
For every marker I added `annotationTypes` and for every `annotationType` I've added `markerAnnotationSpecification`.
My purpose is to color background lines.
In every `markerAnnotationSpecification` I've put different icons and different `colorPreferenceValue`.

The weird thing is this:
When creating the markers everything is fine and even the icons are shown (different icon for every marker) but the background color of the lines is the same for every markers.
I've noticed that the last `markerAnnotationSpecification colorPreferenceValue` is taken every time.
When I changed the order of the `markerAnnotationSpecification` in the `plugin.xml`, the color changed to the last one.

I don't know what to do?

Also I got to the preference page and changed there the annotation type color - after applying I saw it updated the 3 annotation type color to the same color.
Can't I add more then one (I don't think so...)
Can I control the `markerAnnotationSpecification.colorPreferenceValue` programmatically? If so, How?

I'm adding my code - maybe you would see what I don't see:

```
  <extension id="BatonPassing.diff_marker_b"
              name="SiteBDiffMarker"
              point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
      <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker"/>
      <persistent value="true"/>
 </extension>

 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
         <type
             name="diffAnnotationB"
             super="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.info"
             markerType="BatonPassing.diff_marker_b">
             <!--markerSeverity="0"-->
         </type>
   </extension>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification">
         <specification
             icon = "icons/il.gif"
             annotationType="diffAnnotationB"
             verticalRulerPreferenceKey="highlight.rulers.vertical"
             textPreferenceKey="highlight.text"
            colorPreferenceKey="highlight.color"
            highlightPreferenceKey="highlight.background"
            textPreferenceValue="true"
            textStylePreferenceValue="BOX"
            overviewRulerPreferenceKey="highlight.rulers.overview"
            presentationLayer="4"
            highlightPreferenceValue="true"
            label="DiffSiteB"
            symbolicIcon="warning"
            colorPreferenceValue="255,0,0"
            verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true"
            overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"
            textStylePreferenceKey="highlight.text.style" >
        </specification >
    </extension>
```

Every marker code is the same but the id's, names, `colorPreferenceValue` are not.

Please help me. Thank you very very much
Hadas

Answer (score 2):

The colorPreferenceKey should be unique for each of your markerAnnotation specification.  That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still struggling with this problem. You need to change the `presentationLayer` attribute to be separate for every `specification` you have under the `markerAnnotationSpecification`. Preferably so that the highest priority annotation gets the smallest number i.e. `1` and the rest get incremental numbers from there on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're specifying different marker ID type strings when creating them in your plugin's Java code? Just a sanity check...